# col alignment is not fit in small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a row and I put two columns (col-md-2 and col-md-10, col-sm-4). But in mobile view the content is overflowing out of frame.

In normal screen
[image: In normal screen]

In small screen
[image: Here its exceeding the frame limit]

Code part

```html
<div class="row">
     <div class="container listCont" style="height:400px;">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked col-md-2">
    <li class="active"><a href="#class" data-toggle="pill">Class</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lab" data-toggle="pill">Lab</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="scrollbar col-md-10 col-sm-4 " id="scrollstyle" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">
    <div class="tab-content ">
     <div class="tab-pane active " id="class">
      <div class="force-overflow">
       <h4>Pane A</h4>
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
       ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="lab">
      <div class="force-overflow">
       <h4>Pane B</h4>
       <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
       ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you write **viewport** meta tag in the head of your html?

Comment: yes @ChetanKalra

Comment: @ChetanKalra Do you have team viewer account?

Comment: Update your code with CSS. What is the behavior of `force-overflow` class in your page?

Comment: I didn't included width in force-overflow @ChetanKalra

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4? [Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/). *"rows should placed in container.. **only** columns may be immediate children of rows."*

Comment: Could you correct me the code?  @ZimSystem

Comment: Ok , Thanks @ZimSystem

Comment: I resolved the issue.. THanks @ZimSystem

Answer (score -1):

Read the bootstrap docs. Layout should look like this

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). "Not all questions can or should be answered here... 
avoid trying to answer questions which ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem,
...have already been asked and answered many times before"